# Unit testing an IInterceptionBehavior

Tags: c#, unity-container, moq, interceptor

I'm trying to test an implementation of `IInterceptionBehavior`:

```
public class LoggingInterceptorBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        var methodBase = input.MethodBase;

        /* ... */

        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces() { /* ... */ }

    public bool WillExecute { get { return true; } }
}
```

How can I create a fake `MethodBase`?

Comment: What is the actual problem? You can use a standard `MethodInfo` similar to what is suggested in the answers. Or you can create a `Mock<MethodBase>` and `Setup` some `abstract` (or `virtual`) members of the class... But then I do not know what the `MethodBase` is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick seems to be to, rather convolutely, get the `MethodHandle` using reflection and then pass this into a static method off the `MethodBase` class:

```
var methodHandle = dummyClass.GetType().GetMethod("dummyMethod").MethodHandle;

var methodBase = MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(methodHandle);
```

Comment: Is it different from the simpler `var methodBase = dummyClass.GetType().GetMethod("dummyMethod");`? Or maybe `var methodBase = typeof(DummyClass).GetMethod("dummyMethod");`.

Comment: `GetMethod` returns a `MethodInfo` rather that a `MethodBase`.

Comment: But a `MethodInfo` ***is*** a `MethodBase`, so that should be no problem.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen so it is, not sure how I missed that.  If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as so.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be wrong to me. What you seem to need here, is a rather integration test, where you test the whole thing by using it and then checking if it has logged something in the log (or whatever the purpose of the interceptor is). You could create a container, register a dummy test class, execute a method on it, have the method intercepted by the interceptor, etc. you get the gesture.

Comment: Good suggestion, it's probably simple enough to do that, but it's bugging me _out of principle_.